# How can I properly format these four querys?

Tags: php, mysql, count

How can I properly piece these 4 querys together...

```
<?php 
    $units = $query->fetch("SELECT COUNT(*) AS AvailSm FROM units WHERE apartment_name='s'  AND status='A';");
    $units = $query->fetch("SELECT COUNT(*) AS AvailMd FROM units WHERE apartment_name='m'  AND status='A';");
    $units = $query->fetch("SELECT COUNT(*) AS AvailLg FROM units WHERE apartment_name='l'  AND status='A';");
    $units = $query->fetch("SELECT COUNT(*) AS AvailXL FROM units WHERE apartment_name='xl' AND status='A';");
?>
```

... so I can export the count of each size unit using these:

```
<?php echo $units['AvailSm']; ?>
<?php echo $units['AvailMd']; ?>
<?php echo $units['AvailLg']; ?>
<?php echo $units['AvailXL']; ?>
```

...if possible at all. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would start with using `GROUP BY` like :

```
SELECT apartment_name, COUNT(*) AS AvailForThisType 
FROM units WHERE
apartment_name in('s','m','l','xl')  AND status='A'
Group By apartment_name
```

Then figure out how you have to change your `fetch` function to accommodate for that (i.e. to build the array of the counts with apartment_name as the key).